# Can I use a cursor in the select part of a SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, loops, select, cursor, qtsql

I would like to select columns from two tables and add an extra and put this into a table. My question is can I use a cursor to loop through a table and calculate a value and then assign this to the new column in the select part like below

```
    SELECT a.cola,
           a.colB,
           b.colC,
           b.colD,
           (CURSOR TO LOOP THROUGH a table and then calculate some value) as new column
    INTO NEWTABLE
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN b
    ON a.id=b.id
    WHERE etc
```

I just need to know that this is possible?

Comment: nope, not possible in SQL Server

Comment: You are thinking procedurally. sql works best in sets. You have to change your mindset and think about what you want to do to a column instead of what you want to do to each row.

Comment: you can use subquery if only one column will be in result set ,else you can use cross apply

Comment: You can add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery (it does mean you will have to ensure only one value per record is possible to be returned though) but it is far better to do this through joins, if possible, for performance reasons. You should never consider looping as a way to get data if a set-based alternative works.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. From what I have read it would agree with you that joins is a better approach given this language is based on set theory. I think minimizing the use of cursors is the best way to go